# Sumo Logic - Replace value with regex

Tags: sumologic

I'm parsing the `request_uri` from a log file:

```
_sourceName="/opt/zazma/var/logs/AuditRequest.log"
| parse "method=*, statusCode=*, requestURI=*," as method, status_code, request_uri
| count by method, request_uri, status_code
| sort by request_uri
```

The URI includes IDs and email addresses. I want to replace all existing IDs with `'{Id}'` or `'*'`, and all existing emails with `'{email}'`, but Sumo's `REPLACE` function doesn't support regex.

Is there any other way to replace the `value` in the URI?

Comment: This is an old question, but Sumo's Replace function now supports regex: 

`replace(<sourceString>, /<regex>/, <replaceString>) as <field>` 

https://help.sumologic.com/05Search/Search-Query-Language/Search-Operators/replace

Answer (score 2):

You can match the start and end bits each side of the part you want to replace and join them back together later:

```
parse regex "(?<start>.*)(?<guid>[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}?)(?<end>.*?)$" nodrop | concat(start, "{id}", end) as result
```